# Как получить список все участников discord сервера (discord.py)

Tags: python, python-3.x, бот, discord, discord.py

Как можно записать всех участников сервера в list? я пробовал вот так:

```
@bot.command() 
async def members(ctx): 
    for guild in bot.guilds:
        for member in guild.members:
            await ctx.send(member)
```

но выдавало лишь никнейм и тег моего бота

Answer (score 2):

Ваш метод рабочий, проблема заключается в расширениях.
Включите их на портале разработчиков (показаны на скриншоте ниже) и допишите в переменную bot следующее:

```
discord.Intents.all()
```

Чтобы переменная выглядела примерно так:

```
bot = commands.Bot(intents = discord.Intents.all())
```

Учтите, что если ваш бот без верификации, но подключен на 100 серверах - вам потребуется верифицировать бота (иначе не будет работать).
[image]

Comment: теперь выдает ошибку синтаксиса в строке "async def members(ctx): "

Comment: проверьте правильно ли вы всё сделали, возможно вы забыли ')' или закрыть кавычки.

Comment: вместо ник неймов в консоль просто выводиться куча members

Comment: ну, а разве не это делает ваша команда?

Comment: нет она должна выводить никнеймы всех пользователей

Comment: ну так members это и есть пользователь, вы какую-то чушь несёте.

Comment: НИКИ пользователей а не пользователь

Comment: discord.Member, который не принимает атрибутов всегда вернёт вам лишь только имя пользователя. Обращайтесь к документации.